# Google map API crashing

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, itemizedoverlay

I am using the version 1 of the google maps API on my apps with a custom overlap on top. The problem is that on numerous occasion i experience crash and force shutdown on app and I am pretty sure that it is caused by the maps. I checked the threads and I realise that I need to use the populate() function.

The problem is I am not sure where to use it exactly since the code is not written originally by me :(.

```
03-27 10:53:09.440: E/InputEventReceiver(28709): Exception dispatching input event.
03-27 10:53:09.440: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709): Exception in MessageQueue callback:     handleReceiveCallback
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItemsAtLocation(ItemizedOverlay.java:617)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItemAtLocation(ItemizedOverlay.java:586)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.handleMotionEvent(ItemizedOverlay.java:498)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTouchEvent(ItemizedOverlay.java:572)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTouchEvent(OverlayBundle.java:63)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:681)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7337)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2145)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
03-27 10:53:09.490: E/MessageQueue-JNI(28709):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
```

Here is my itemized overlay class which is causing trouble

```
public class AdvrItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<MapOverlayItem> {

protected Vector<AdvrMapItem> mOverlayItems = new Vector<AdvrMapItem>();

protected Bitmap mEmptyMarker = null;

protected Resources mResources = null;

protected Rect mDstRect = new Rect(6, 6, 66, 66);

public AdvrItemizedOverlay(Resources res) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_map_mark_adver)));
    mEmptyMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bg_map_mark_adver);
    float density = (float)mEmptyMarker.getWidth() / 72.0f;
    mDstRect.left *= density;
    mDstRect.top *= density;
    mDstRect.right *= density;
    mDstRect.bottom *= density;
    mResources = res;
    performPopulated();
}

@Override
protected MapOverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    AdvrMapItem advrItem = mOverlayItems.get(i);
    MapOverlayItem overlayItem = advrItem.overlayItem();
    Drawable marker = advrItem.mapMarker(mResources, mEmptyMarker, mDstRect);
    if (marker != null)
        overlayItem.setMarker(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    return overlayItem;

}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlayItems.size();
}

public void add(AdvrMapItem userItem) {
    mOverlayItems.add(userItem);
    populate();
}

public void remove(AdvrMapItem item) {
    mOverlayItems.remove(item);
    setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
    populate();
}

public void clear() {
    mOverlayItems.removeAllElements();
    setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
    populate();
}

public void performPopulated() { populate(); }
```

}

I am not sure exactly when is the constructor being called and where to place the populate method. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You passed it a null marker at some point.  You'll need to find out where.  You may also want to consider updating-  not only is the API simpler in version 2, but they don't hand out new v1 api keys anymore/